# Elasticsearch return distinct property values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

I have collection of Products with property Brand and 2 unique values:

- "Super brand A"
- "Super brand B"

ES query

```
     var response = new ElasticClient().Search<DTO>(s => s
           .Index("index")
           .Type("type")
           .Aggregations(a => a
               .Terms("unique", t => t
                   .Field(f => f.Brand)
                   //.Field(f => f.Brand.Suffix("keyword"))
                   .Size(1000)
               )
           )
         );

        var brands = (((BucketAggregate)response.Aggregations.First().Value).Items).Cast<KeyedBucket<Object>>().Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

ES returns 4 invalid values

- "Super"
- "brand"
- "A"
- "B"

I've tried to force full property match by adding .Suffix("keyword") to field but then it returns empty list. How can I get 2 distinct values?

Comment: Looks like the Brand field is of type string. If you make it of type keyword  your query should work as is. Or you can try f.Brand.Keyword if you do not want to change the mapping

Comment: @sramalingam24

[Or you can try f.Brand.Keyword if you do not want to change the mapping]

could you explain this part a little bit more?

Comment: In latest ES every string field has an unanalyzed keyword field(not split into tokens like the string field). So if you want the entire string to be considered a single term you can use Brand.Keyword field